# Navigation menu in reverse and not aligned with logo

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a horizontal navigation menu in my vue3 application.  I have 2 problems.

1. My menu is reversed and not in the correct order. 2) My menu does not align with the logo. Below is an image of what it looks like
   [image]

   ```
    <template>
     <header>
     <nav class="navbar">
     <img src="src\assets\logo.svg" height="50px" width="50px" />
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
   ```

   ---

   ```
   <style scoped>
    .navbar {
     background-color: white;
      border-radius: 30px;
    }

    .navbar li {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
     margin: 13px 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
   }

   .navbar ul {
    overflow: auto;
   }

   .navbar li a {
    padding: 3px 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    }
    </style>
   ```

Comment: Use position:abolsute on your `<img>` tag. This may help: https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use flexbox model instead of float like this:

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 13px 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar li a {
  padding: 3px 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Vue.js_Logo_2.svg/512px-Vue.js_Logo_2.svg.png" height="50px" width="50px" />
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```